# Docusign | Embedded Signing | How can sender share the "recipient signing URL" with recipient/signer?

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature

I've a use-case to integrate e-signature with an existing application of some confidential customer.

While exploring docusign, i've found that there are two ways to get e-signatures:

1. Remote - Sending signing link in the email.
2. Embedded - Within any application.

Remote way is clear to me.
But, Embedded way is not clear and my query is regarding the embedded only:

I've a sample use-case:
Suppose, Tom is my user who wanna get a document signed from another user Pedro.
So Tom would:

1. hit an API to create an envelope, with all the documents encapsulated in it.
2. Then tom would generate the recipient signing URL.

Now, **how would Tom send this URL to Pedro**. Because at the end Pedro need to sign it.

NOTE: I'm not sure if above is the actual way to use embedded. **If not, can anybody help me with a real use-case of using embedded.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. With embedded signing, the signer signs from your web site/web application. Email is usually not involved.

Example:

- Tom is a human resources manager.
- Pedro sends Tom an email announcing that he has bought a house and the company should update its records.
- Tom opens his HR application and enters Pedro's new address into an "Address Change form" that results in a DocuSign envelope being created. Pedro will later sign the form (via the DocuSign envelope) to certify that his address has changed.
- Pedro is told to go to his company's internal web site. There he logs in and the application sends him to the embedded DocuSign signing ceremony so he can sign his address change form.

Or another example that shows how Tom does not need to create the envelope:

- Pedro is a customer of Tom's company.
- Pedro has his own login on Tom's customer web portal application.
- Pedro logs into the web portal, and starts a new order for himself.
- The web portal creates the order in a DocuSign envelope for Pedro, sends it, and then enables Pedro to sign the order using an embedded signing ceremony.
- Now that the order is signed by Pedro, the web portal starts the order fulfilment process within Tom's company.

Note: since DocuSign can collect payments as part of an order, Pedro could also be automatically asked to pay at the time he orders.

Comment: Thanks @Larry K, for the beautiful explanation.

2nd use-case shared by you is totally clear where Tom does't come into picture.


But, i've query regarding the first use-case shared by you.
The query is: Who is creating the envelope ? Is Tom creating it ?

Comment: Yes, in the first example, which is a bit contrived, Tom is creating the envelope. It is then waiting in the DocuSign system until Pedro is ready to sign it.

Comment: Thanks @Larry. 
"Tom is creating the envelope" that's fine. After envelope creation, there is need to create "signing URL" which remains valid for some time(as per my understanding). Who is creating that URL ? Is it Tom again ? If yes, how is he sharing it with Pedro.

Comment: Please ask your new question as a separate question on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is designed to be a question/answer system, not a back-and-forth discussion system. Thank you.

Comment: sure @Larry K. I can post a new question. The only reason, i was commenting on this only because my queries are related to your answer. Not sure, how to refer this answer in that question. Let me try. Thank you.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911209/docusign-embedded-signing-who-and-when-generates-the-signing-url