# Docusign | Embedded Signing | Who and When generates the "signing URL"?

Tags: docusignapi

I've a use-case to integrate e-signature with an existing application of some confidential customer.

Use-Case:
Tom is a human resources manager.
Tom wants his customer Pedro to sign a document.

Tom would create an envelope. 
Pedro should have the link i.e. "signing URL" where he can sign that document.

Now, who would hit POST API to create that "signing URL" ? Is it Tom ? If yes, then does he need to share that link with Pedro and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is: is Pedro a remote signer (receives the invitation to the signing ceremony via email) or an embedded signer (uses Tom's web portal).

For remote signers, the default is that when Tom sends the envelope, DocuSign will send an email to Pedro inviting him to sign.

For embedded signers, when Pedro next logs into the web portal built by Tom's team:

1. the web portal software will know that it wants Pedro to sign the envelope using embedded signing.
2. the web portal will obtain a DocuSign access token using JWT grant.
3. the web portal will use the access token to obtain a signing url for the envelope.
4. the web portal will redirect Pedro's browser to the signing ceremony
5. Pedro signs. This is considered embedded signing since it is done within the flow of the web portal.
6. DocuSign, as directed by the signing url request, will re-direct Pedro's browser back to the web portal app.
7. Pedro is still logged into the web portal and can now do other tasks within the portal

Comment: Thanks @Larry K, It's the case of Embedded Signing only. I got it as "Tom would be creating the envelope." and "It is the Web Portal which would be obtain a signing url". Tom's job is just to create the envelope and "web portal" would be responsible for obtaining the signing url. Can you please confirm if this understanding is correct ?

Comment: Yes, correct. The signing ceremony url is only good for a couple of minutes. So it must be requested immediately before the signer is redirected to the signing ceremony url.